# Angular 5 - Angular Material - show districts after selecting a country

Tags: angular-material, angular5

In my angular5 application I have this form:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({    
  institution: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
  color: [''],
  ...
  addressesWithProducts: this.formBuilder.array([])
});
```

In order to add a new **addressWithProducts** I use this method:

```
addAddress() {
    let addressWithProducts = this.formBuilder.group({
      address: this.formBuilder.group({
        ...
        country: ['', [Validators.minLength(2)]],
        provinceType: ['', [Validators.minLength(2)]],
        provinceTypesOfAddressWithProducts: [['test1', 'test2', 'test3']],
        ...
      })
    });
    let addressesWithProducts: FormArray = 
    this.form.controls['addressesWithProducts'] as FormArray;
    addressesWithProducts.push(addressWithProducts);
}
```

I will show **test1, test2 and test3** with:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    ...
    <div formArrayName="addressesWithProducts">
        <mat-form-field style="width:95%">
            <mat-select placeholder="District" formArrayName="provinceTypesOfAddressWithProducts">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let provinceType of provinceTypesOfAddressWithProducts" [value]="provinceType">
                    {{provinceType | translate}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

but no values are shown in select. Does anyone have any hint in order to get it work?

Comment: There is no 'formControlArray' directive - did you mean 'formArrayName'?

Comment: Yes, sry I ment 'formArrayName' - I changed it but it is still not working: test1, test2 and test3 are not shown in <mat-select />